# Where should I ask a question about whether a university is respected in Germany?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to find out if a particular university is respected in Germany, but I'm not sure where to ask it. Where can I ask such a question?

Answer (score 5):

[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) may be the site for your question. Note that:

- Asking about a specific institution is off topic. For example, this similar question was closed: [What is the status/reputation of the University of South Africa (UNISA)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10728/56207)
- More general questions have been well-received: [How can I evaluate whether a school has developed a poor reputation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/195454/56207)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question and made it more general rather than about a specific university (as it is not actually about the university, but rather about how Germans feel about Polish degrees)

Answer (score 4):

The [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) site looks like it has questions related to univeristies, specifically the [ranking](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranking) tag:

> Questions about formal rankings of universities...

Comment: I'll try, hopefully it doesn't get closed.